# No permission to get cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension

im having trouble accessing cookies for a game called roblox. I am trying to make a guest id changer so you can be any guest id. but i can not seem to get the cookie

manifest.json file: https://pastebin.com/s0xAxf74
main.js: https://pastebin.com/WD5j5xsR

error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running cookies.get: No host permissions for cookies at url: "http://.roblox.com/".
    at chrome-extension://clpnmiebajadjhpjamncibjkkjicnkcn/main.js:3:16
```

Comment: You are referencing http in your main.js, the site seems to run on https. Chrome giving access to cookies to extensions... [This](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies) is not how it's meant to be.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code here. It's highly discouraged to have code in pastebin as it makes it non-searchable here and links can become broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `http://roblox.com` or `http://*.roblox.com` instead of `http://.roblox.com`.

I checked your code with described fix and it works.

Comment: Just to clarify, in match patterns `*.roblox.com` includes `roblox.com`.